# C function pointer declaration omitting parameters

Tags: c, function-pointers, function-parameter

In the code, I omitted parameters for `int (*bar)` and assigned `&foo`, which as 3 arguments, to `bar`. `(*bar)` received the numbers and gave me a return value. I thought this is ok but I've heard that this is actually UB. How does `(*bar)` receive the numbers? Thx

```
#include <stdio.h>

int foo(int a, int b, int c){
    return a+b+c;
}

int main(void) {
    int (*bar)() = &foo;
    printf("%d", bar(1, 2, 3));
    return 0;
}
```

**edit**
When I pass more than three arguments to `bar()` (say 5 arguments), the program works. Where do the two extra arguments go?

Comment: Where are you using bar?

Comment: A function declaration with an empty argument list means the function takes an unknown number of argument, each of unknown type. The first use of the function will tell the compiler the number and types of arguments.

Comment: I've edited the code. The program still works and my question remains. Thx

Comment: `(*bar)` is not "receiving numbers." It's being assigned the address of `foo()` so that you *can* call it with the 3 arguments, as you do.

Comment: I'm not sure, but I think I had some problems once where this thing was the cause.

Comment: @WeatherVane does `*(bar)` need to know the number of arguments? Also is that UB?

Comment: No: it has to be a compatible function, and as commented, the arguments are not stated, so it is. Consider the the parallel of `int x; int *ptr = &x;` The pointer is a compatible type but the value held by `x` is irrelevant (for that purpose).

Comment: How the arguments are received depends on the calling convention. I think omitting the arguments is only safe if the function takes types not subject to the default promotions (say not short or float) and it's not variadic (because variadics may have a different calling convention)